# Is this a good way to create a short UID for a URL?

Tags: php, url, uniqueidentifier, uid

Hey guys, I am trying to find a way to generate a UID to be placed in a URL. Right now I am looking at ways to create a UID's without using a sequential index from a db. This is what I have come up with.

As far as I can tell this should only create duplicates if they are both created in the same 1/10000th of a second.

```
function uid()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());

    $prec = 5;
    $usec = round($usec, $prec); 
    $sec = round($sec - ($sec / 1.001), $prec);

    $time = ($sec + $usec);

    return base_convert($time, 10, 36);
}
```

Any ideas on why this function would be a bad idea?

Comment: GUID is great but this function creates id's like so: '5wxhr3k'. They are quite short.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the real uid functionality of PHP? This should provide truly unique identifiers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

As for a v4 compliant UUID, check this topic: [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Maybe because autoincrement integers are mainly meant for this?
Still there is a possibility of equal ids

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Hash functions like MD5, SHA1, CRC32, etc. are best suited for this. Bear in mind that the shorter your hash key, the greater the likelihood of collisions.