# How to generate a UUID in this format?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

I've been looking all over the web for this. Im trying to make a UUID which will appear in this format: 32321-65631-43546-54542 (the numbers of course, will vary) I know how to make a uniqid id, but dont know where to start with this. Anybody know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Should this “UUID” comply with some [specific requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)?

Comment: no, i just want it to generate a 4 sectioned id with 5 numbers in each section.

Comment: I don't see how my answer below can't do this? Generate 4 5 digit numbers and switch the x's to d's if you are only going to be used decimals rather than hex.

Comment: You can use either one of these generators to easily create UUID or GUIDs (basically same thing): [Online UUID Generator](http://www.onlineuuidgenerator.com) [Online GUID Generator](http://www.onlineguidgenerator.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can find your answer here:

[PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2040240/751151)

and here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

**Second Edit**

Using the answer in the first link:

```
$uuid = sprintf('%05d-%05d-%05d-%05d',
  mt_rand( 0, 99999),
  mt_rand( 0, 99999),
  mt_rand( 0, 99999),
  mt_rand( 0, 99999)
 );
```

Bear in mind this is not a 'proper' UUID, as it is not going to be Universally unique (among other things). This is really just a random 20 digit hyphenated ID.

Comment: Neither of these approaches provide the right format, as is.

Comment: A bit harsh.. It would take *very* little effort to change the function in the linked answer to generate the format specified.

Comment: sorry, not what im looking for.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how you generate the UUID/numbers in the UUID then?

Comment: @user796855, if this isn't what you are looking for, then you better clarify your question, as this answer seems fine to me.

Comment: The answer currently reads "just string some number together four times", which does not help the OP to generate a reliably _unique_ UUID in the requested format. In retrospect I have removed my downvote, but I won't upvote it...

Comment: @Colin: If it's "_very_ little effort", perhaps you can do that in your answer, then? :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you question correctly: You have your number (*...I know how to make a uniqid id...*), but are searching for a way to format it properly, try this:

```
$number = '32321656314354654542';
echo implode('-', str_split($number, 5));
```

**Output**:

```
32321-65631-43546-54542
```