# Pseudo-random-looking one-to-one int32->int32 function

Tags: algorithm, random, integer, bijection

I am looking for a int32->int32 function that is

- bijection (one-to-one correspondence)
- cheap to calculate at least in one direction
- transforms the increasing sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, ... into a sequence looking like a good pseudo-random sequence (~ half bits flip when argument changes by a small number, no obvious patterns)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Similar question: [Obfuscating an ID](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8554286/1009831).

Comment: How cheap is "cheap"? Any reasonable block cipher should offer your pseudo-random/bit flip desire.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiply by a large odd number and xor with a different one.

Bijection: odd numbers have a multiplicative inverse modulo powers of two, so the multiplication is undone by a multiplication by the inverse. And xor is, of course, undone by another xor.

This is basically how the linear congruence pseudo random number generator works.

Answer (score 3):

Probably an overkill for this task, but have you consider applying any crypto [pseudo random permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) or other primitives comes from [block ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher). For example, it may be done using des with known key in counter mode:

```
younumber xor (des (key, number counter))
```