# Any clue on what hash was used in this?

Tags: php, hash

I want to know what it was used for this to hash

```
2418c997-4a7b-4bd1-8297-f7c5ce7d75e0
```

Also how come this 2418c997-4a7b-4bd1-8297-f7c5ce7d75e0`.axd` can show a photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not a hash... looks like a [uuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: using PHP how can I construct one?

Comment: using google :) http://bit.ly/pt3nNj

Comment: I see. Can I have an input to be used to create a uuid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid/2040279#2040279