# Create Random Serial with PHP

Tags: php

I want to have a random serial created on my website everytime someone visits.

The format of the serial should be XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX.

X represents a random number or capital letter.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this. Could anybody please help me out?

So for example the random serial output could be: 3WT4A-NB34O-JU87P-B3UHS

Thanks a lot!

Comment: take a look at http://de.php.net/rand and http://php.net/manual/de/function.range.php .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are most certainly better ways of doing it, but this is the first that jumps to mind:

```
$chars = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
$serial = '';
$max = count($chars)-1;
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
    $serial .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').$chars[rand(0, $max)];
}
```

**05/26/13 Edit:** It's advised to keep the [Count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function outside of the loop. The reason for this is that you don't want to expend the extra clock cycles running this function through each iteration when you can simply run it once.

Comment: Hey `($i % 5 ? '-' : '')` is not correct, it puts like every dash after every 2 chars. Can you fix this, please?

Comment: Sorry about that. Had the logic a little backwards. It works now.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is to calculate the four segments as random numbers in base 36.

```
function generate_serial() {
    static $max = 60466175; // ZZZZZZ in decimal
    return strtoupper(sprintf(
        "%05s-%05s-%05s-%05s",
        base_convert(random_int(0, $max), 10, 36),
        base_convert(random_int(0, $max), 10, 36),
        base_convert(random_int(0, $max), 10, 36),
        base_convert(random_int(0, $max), 10, 36)
    ));
}
```

Comment: The more I look at this answer, the more I like it. This is a brilliant way of handling the problem without relying on clumsy iterations. Additionally, `mt_rand` is significantly faster than `rand`.

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward solution would be something like this.

```
$tokens = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

$serial = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
        $serial .= $tokens[rand(0, 35)];
    }

    if ($i < 3) {
        $serial .= '-';
    }
}

echo $serial;
```

Sample output:

```
51C8A-P9NZD-UM37Q-YKZHO
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a bunch of ways to approach this. One simple one is:

```
$string1 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
$string2 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
$string3 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
$string4 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -5, 5);
$serial  = sprintf('%s-%s-%s-%s', $string1, $string2, $string3, $string4);
```

There are better ways to generate random strings then this but this would give you the basic functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function rand_string( $length ) {
    $length += 3;
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";  
    $str= "";
    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
            if($i == 5 || $i == 11 || $i == 17 )
                $str .= '-';
            else
                $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }

    return $str;
}

$getstring = rand_string(20,5);
echo $getstring;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this serial just because of uniqueness - you could also try to use [UUID v4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29), as described in one of answers here: [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of such answers at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356295/1091195

You can use the random string generator mentioned there, either you use it once to get a 20 letter string then insert dashes, or you can call it 4 times for 5 letter and concat the results.