# How to implement a ‘Globally Unique IDs’ in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook

How could I replicate Facebook's allocation of a unique ID to a vast range of resources? See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

With Facebook every photo, person, event, page has a unique ID.

If I wanted to make every page have a unique ID all I would need to do is have a page table with ID that auto increments.
But this is not what I want to achieve, I want to achieve a system like Facebook has, where every object ("resource") has a unique ID.

Comment: Only unique or unique and unpredictable?

Comment: Like Facebook - unique - refer link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function; UUIDs are the generally accepted way to generate unique keys of this variety.

That said, using MySQL's UUID function will conflict with statement-based replication; if you are currently, or may in the future, use this method of replication, consider using whatever UUID-generating mechanism your language provides. As UUIDs are a standard, any reasonable programming language will have a mechanism available to generate them; for Python, for instance, this is the [uuid module](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html). For PHP, a [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function is available in the standard library, though this is not a standards-compliant UUID.

You might see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid), directly on-point for generating standards-compliant UUIDs from PHP.

Comment: Would Facebook use something like UUID.
I'm using PHP
Thanks for the very fast reply as well.

Comment: @user1433654 Yes. As I said, they're the generally accepted approach.