# Generate unique ascendant ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a good practice about generating unique big IDs like Google+ or facebook has.
Existing questions was a bout generating a unique ID not an ascendant one (`uniqid()` was a good way to go on).
We may rely to something basically ascendant like Timestamp `time()` when the user signs up, or ID of the User table `$id`, maybe:

- `ID = time() - 123456789 + $id`.
- Or just ID of User table, like `$id + 123456789`
  If we add always the same constant integer, we won't get collisions.

We can't use `uniqid()` to generate an ascendant ID.
And to make the auto-increment step of the database more than 1 isn't enough to have a big integer in all cases.
**what do you suggest?**

Comment: Why do you want to have big integer? What's the point of doing this? Just curious.

Comment: you know that facebook doesn't really generate big ids...it just came to that..retroactively I saw really small ids on facebook. Just saying.

Comment: If you really want big numbers I would just use the table ID which is allways unique and add a constant number. The "problem" is that after a while (a very long while) you will get 10 digit ID's instead of 9 digits. Well, that is: if this bothers you.

Comment: @Matthias, no that's good in any cases.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at this answer that explains how to generate v4 UUID in PHP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid) or have a look at this post, that goes through 4 ways of [creating unique IDs in PHP](http://phpgoogle.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/four-ways-to-generate-unique-id-by-php.html) (some of them involve uniqid() though)