# Generate 128 bit hex number

Tags: php

I would like to generate a random 128 bit hex number in PHP.

How can I do that?

Comment: The only way to guarantee that it is unique is to store what you have already generated.  Do you truly want unique, or just random?

Comment: Random number should do ! Thanks !

Comment: Make a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)? It is 128-bit.

Comment: A) loop (random -> hex digits -> 0 padding) B) random -> md5 -> slice

Comment: @KarolyHorvath why slice an md5 hash, it's already 128 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest I know of:

```
$str = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
```

You can also build a string of 16 characters by appending the character at every loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i != 16; ++$i) {
    $str .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
}
```

To turn it into hex, use `bin2hex($str)`. Alternatively, generate a UUID v4 as described in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875555/1338292) I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 7, `random_bytes` is the best method of generating random data, but you can use the [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) library to add forward-compatible support for `random_bytes()` to older versions of the language. This library defines the function based on the *best* fallback method, including the otherwise mentioned `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

```
// generates 64-character (256-bit) key
function generate_256bit() {
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}

// generates 32-character (128-bit) key
function generate_128bit() {
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
}

// 256-bit: f3af82d0bedc3a91b3b5a51beefe553e33a17912de45d3302ed0216ad867cd55
// 128-bit: 4d7245e2d61cfcce2feafd7e687cdb0e
```

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.3:

```
$rand128_hex = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function string_random($characters, $length)
    {
    $string = '';
    for ($max = mb_strlen($characters) - 1, $i = 0; $i < $length; ++ $i)
        {
        $string .= mb_substr($characters, mt_rand(0, $max), 1);
        }
    return $string;
    }

// 128 bits is 16 bytes; 2 hex digits to represent each byte
$random_128_bit_hex = string_random('0123456789abcdef', 32);
// $random_128_bit_hex might be: '4374e7bb02ae5d5bc6d0d85af78aa2ce'
```