# Generating unique 5 alpha-numeric IDs in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, alphanumeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

May i know how or what is the simplest HTML/PHP codes to generate 5 alpha-numeric randomizer IDs? I have seen other question similar to what i was asking, but it is not what i have been looking for.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?  You *may* know, but so far I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

use the Uniqid function http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php