# Memcache and Mysqli Insert statement Advice

Tags: php, mysqli, memcached

Ok I have been working my way around Memcache for the last few days, attempting to collate the most helpful articles I can find (Primarily from Stackoverflow)

I understand creating a value using a key in memcache and have read that correct/efficient key naming is important. The best way it seems to make a key unique is to use the $id. My question is how can I make a key unique without having the $id (if for example that $id is just auto incremented within my Mysqli database table)

An example of Memcache inserting and retrieving is the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products SET id = $id, name = $name";
// Run Insert Query Here using prepared statement
if (success === TRUE)
{
    //set a key
    $key = 'product_'.$id ;
    $product = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name);
    $memcache->set($key, $product);
}
```

This I believe will work fine, but my question is how could I make the key unique if I do not have access to the $id? As I could use the name, but there is a possibility that two users could have the same name.

I hope this makes sense. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a unique ID,

3 solutions :

- with [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uniqid.php)
- with this solution [UUID generator](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=php%20uuid&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid&ei=3K0TUc29A7GZ0QXM-4C4CQ&usg=AFQjCNHUn2wnEn6nFSZ3rDCPLUG01rNujg&bvm=bv.42080656,d.d2k)
- hash of string (ex : md5('table_name_id:'.$id) or sha1('table_name_id:'.$id) )

Comment: Arh, why did I not think of this. I assume I would have to store the uniqid() within my mysqli database? So everything correlates.

Comment: you have to generate a uniqid or uuid for each element of your database, and index the field.
Don't drop the autoincrment id, it's always useful.

Comment: You can eventually generate a key with a hash of your id
md5($id)
or a hash of a string
md5('table_name_id:'.$id)
so you can retrieve your key without extra field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL to automatically generate IDs for you (via an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column), then why not ask MySQL for the ID it gave to the new row with [`$mysqli->insert_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)?

Example:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("insert into products set name='best product ever'");
if ($result === TRUE) {
    // put it into memcached
    $key = 'product_' . $mysqli->insert_id();
    $product = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name);
    $memcache->set($key, $product);
}
```

Comment: The question was : "how could I make the key unique if I do not have access to the $id"

Comment: I know, but the OP mentioned using MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT` to generate IDs. It is then imho reasonable to assume that the OP didn't know about the `mysqli::insert_id()` method. While it is not a literal solution to the question, my answer offers an alternative solution to the underlying problem, which is _getting the ID_. If the OP would rather generate IDs himself, he has your answer to refer to. :-)