# Laravel 4 database statement create trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, pdo, laravel

During the creation process of my app's migration files, I noticed that Laravel does not support database triggers! I have come to terms with the fact that I need to execute a query statement to accomplish this, but that is also giving me troubles.. Here is a code snippet from my app:

```
Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('uuid', 36);
    $table->string('email', 255);
    $table->string('password', 255);
});
DB::statement('CREATE TRIGGER users_trigger_uuid BEFORE INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.uuid = UUID()');
```

When I run artisan migrate it gives me the following error:

> [Exception]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet (SQL: CREATE TRIGGER users_trigger_uuid BEFORE INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.uuid = UUID()) (Bindings: array (
>   ))

Are there any solutions apart from creating my own PDO object and executing the query outside of Laravel? Is this a MySQL exception or a Laravel exception?

**EDIT**

Judging by the exception, it's clear that prepared statements don't support the creation of triggers.. not sure why but would love some insight. To get around this I just ran my own PDO query.

```
$default_driver = Config::get('database.default');
$connection_info = Config::get('database.connections.' . $default_driver);
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $connection_info['host'] . ';dbname=' . $connection_info['database'], $connection_info['username'], $connection_info['password']);
$conn->query('CREATE TRIGGER users_trigger_uuid BEFORE INSERT ON ' . $connection_info['prefix'] . 'users FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.uuid = UUID()');
```

Comment: whilst the answer you have selected is simple and 'eloquent' it doesn't address a serious database integrity issue. You should try and wrap the database code in a transaction so that if anything fails, it all fails.

Comment: Did you have luck with this?

Answer (score 8):

Use DB::unprepared(), works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

The "clean" way to do this is to use *database events*. When you create a new User instance, Laravel4 fires a `created` event.

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various
>   points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: creating,
>   created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted.
>
> Whenever a new item is saved for the first time, the creating and
>   created events will fire. If an item is not new and the save method is
>   called, the updating / updated events will fire. In both cases, the
>   saving / saved events will fire.

So, inside your User class, add a listener for the `creating` event:

```
class User extends Eloquent ... {

    // ...

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($user)
        {
            $user->uuid = uuid();
        });
    }
```

For how to generate a UUID in PHP, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid).

Comment: need to be very careful using this solution. It doesn't appear like the database modifying code is wrapped in a transaction. Your database could end up in an awful state if you aren't careful.

Comment: Creation ought to be atomic; here we are modifying a *tuple* before it is actually `INSERT`ed. It is however possible to transact statements by modifying or overriding `"vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php` `run()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you show in your edit is not correct. You should either use `DB::unprepared()`, or, if you must use PDO, **do not do it that way**. Instead, get a PDO object from the connection and use that:

`$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();`