# Generate Api key

Tags: php

I need to generate an api key which should be unique and should never conflict. I think if I combine some stuff with unix timestamp then it would be possible. If someone can tell me more specific in php would be appreciable.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid

Comment: Universally Unique Identifier. Globally Unique Identifier. Both known as UUID or GUID, that should produce sufficient googling material. A simple function exists, called `uniqid()` in PHP. MySQL has UUID() function that does the similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). There are [some nice implementations](https://packagist.org/search/?q=uuid) in Packagist

Comment: I think that OP wanted a php thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php to generate uniq IDs as a starting point. and then combine them with extra salts that you build yourself to give you the assurance that the ID is valid and not easily faked by someone else.