# Generatinge Unique Id on the fly Mysql + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am trying to come up with a solution to generate a Unique Id preferably on the Fly. Usage scope could be Order, Product or Plan Id, where there is no security involved.

I don't like idea of generating a random number and then querying the db to check its uniqueness and repeating the process if it is not in this case where security isn't an issue.

Also I don't prefer using Auto Increment id since it looks so simple.

My initial thought is to use a combination of Auto Increment id + timestamp converting the decimal value to hex so it looks like a random string. And then finally prefixing and suffixing it with 2 digit random string.

```
function generateUID($num){
    $str = dechex(time()+ intval($num));
    $prefix = dechex(rand(1,15));
    $suffix = dechex(rand(1,15));

    return strtoupper($suffix.$str.$prefix);

}
```

Where $num is the auto_increment id
Returns something like `E53D42A046`

Is this the right way to go about doing this, are there collision issues ?

**I thank all responses..!**

I acknowledge the usefulness of uniqid() but in this context to be genuinely unique Auto_Increment need to play a significant part so how will it do so in uniqid. Passing it as a prefix would result in a Product id which vary greatly in size. (153d432da861fe, 999999953d432f439bc0).

To expand the scope further, Ideally we want a unique code which **looks** random with fairly consistent length and could be reversed to the auto_increment id from which it was created.

Comment: You can use a mix of UNIX timestamp along with a random function. You'll be guaranteed uniqueness with no collisions. *"Also I don't prefer using Auto Increment id since it looks so simple."* - Sometimes, even the things that appear to be the most simple, can be just as effective.

Comment: Ok gr8..  I guess then what I did, adding UNIX timestamp with auto increment id should be unique 100%?

Comment: Yes, along with an auto increment, that would be extremely hard to get a collision, and I mean "extremely".

Comment: As per the manual on [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) - *Can be useful, for instance, if you generate identifiers simultaneously on several hosts that might happen to generate the identifier at the same microsecond.* - ***Warning**
This function does not create random nor unpredictable strings. This function must not be used for security purposes. Use a cryptographically secure random function/generator and cryptographically secure hash functions to create unpredictable secure IDs.*

Answer (score 2):

Such a function already exists - `uniqid()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

It works based on the timestamp down to the microsecond - you can add a prefix based on the process ID to further refine it.  There are a couple more robust versions out there as well - see [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

Comment: But can I rely on that in the context of assigning id without querying the table for uniqueness.

Comment: @Samosa Just put a UNIQUE constraint on the column, and if there's an error, generate another id.

Comment: @Samosa - unless you're generating multiple IDs in the same microsecond, yes, it's guaranteed to be unique.  If you are, you might want to use `http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php` as the prefix value

Comment: If you're generating multiple IDs in the same script, then the pid will also be the same.

Comment: @DaveChen - yes, but php is a largely a single-threaded language - you can generate IDs in the same script in sequence, but not in parallel.  Internally, uniqid() includes a very short delay, which prevents successive calls from using the same timestamp.

Comment: @SamDufel I'm only pointing out that there's always a chance of a collision within the database. The surr method is to add a unique column so that you don't query and check if the column already exists (racing condition).