# Why isn't this PHP returning an increased variable value?

Tags: php

I dont have a database. But I would like the server to send me a unique number for each of my uploads. I have written the Server side is written in PHP. I have defined a global values as fileId and assigned 1 to it at the begining. Then I do an auto increment of it. But for all my uploads I get one (the same number as the begining). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<?php

$fileId = 1;

class UploadController {

  private static function uploadRequest() {
    echo self::$PARAM_FILE_ID . "=" . $GLOBALS['fileId'];
    $GLOBALS['fileId'] = $GLOBALS['fileId'] + 1;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Every time you run the script, you set the variable to `1`. Variables don't persist across different runs of the same script. If you don't have a database, put it in a file.

Comment: Use Database, data source...

Comment: You could count the number of files in your upload directory and return count + 1 as fileid, if you don't want to use sessions or a database

Comment: You don't need a database, you could store them in a file and use `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose`.

Comment: You could look at using [UUID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid/15875555#15875555) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are only global to the current request.

There's no way to do that in PHP itself.

You have to use either a database or some sort of cache mechanism (even if only filesystem based).

Comment: You will have to use some database or file to retain the value as PHP variables are per session.