# Shortest unique ID based on date and time?

Tags: php, time

What is the shortest unique ID that can be created with PHP but without using a database? I guess it's something based on date+time (24 hour time format?) but how short can it be?

Comment: Depends on how often you need it.

Comment: This question is a solution looking for a problem to solve. Why dont you state the problem and give some context if you want some valuable input ?

Comment: How many unique ids are you going to need? That will determine the number of bits that you must have to make sure that there will be enough unique ids.

Answer (score 1):

For an PHP inbuilt solution you could look into `uniqid` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

```
$id = uniqid('',true);
```

Alternatively you could create a `UUID`. For example see: [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2040240/505722)