# What is the best way to generate a non-duplicate uuid (v4) in PHP

Tags: php, guid, uuid

I am using the following function, it uses `mt_rand` but there is chance, I believe, that it could generate a duplicate. Is there a better way to do this?

```
 sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x', mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000, mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000, mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

Comment: That question does not answer my problem. I am specifically looking for advice on creating non-duplicates. It doesn't have to be random, just unique.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, the problem is 'slim' = 'possible', even if its insanely unlikely. I think I might just have to perform a duplicate check through the database.

Comment: your code DOES NOT generate an UUID4 - it doesn't have the **4** in the required position. If you want a non-duplicate could you just auto increment it at every function call?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create real UUID v4 in PHP then the best thing to do is use this package - https://github.com/ramsey/uuid - that has been thoroughly tested and is used by many other packages.