# Never repeating integers PHP

Tags: php, integer, unique

I am integrating a third party web service which requires a unique integer for each call and once that integer is consumed, it does not accept that integer ever again. It will be a real-time integration, i-e there can be multiple calls to that web services from multiple users on the website this means that there can also be simultaneous calls if more than one user calls that web-service.

For now I tried PHP's `uniqid()` method to generate a unique id for each transaction but as it does not guarantee unique integers always.

Also I tried UNIX's Epoch seconds as required integer which works perfectly but I know it will not work with simultaneous calls.

I don't require random numbers, it can be anything which will never repeat. Please suggest possible solutions.

Comment: How big is the space you can use (integer width)? Does it *have* to be an integer?

Comment: Unix epoch *plus* a large random number from `mt_rand` should make a duplicate integer extraordinarily unlikely. Something like `$id = time() . mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);`

Comment: 32-bit integer is sufficient. and Yes it has to be an integer as per web-service requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a database table with an auto-incrementing primary key and use that number. Insert a row for each call to the 3rd party service.

### Update:

Based on your comment in another answer I recommend using a queue so that failures may be re-tried:

> The call to Web-service deals with sending thousands of dollars. If a call will ever fail, that will be a very serious issue...

Your queue can either be implemented in a simple database table and use the primary key as mentioned above, or you can use a full-blown queue service.

Comment: I hope that there will be more efficient solution.

Comment: How many inserts/second do you reasonably need for your use case?

Comment: Who knows! there can be thousands of users online at same time using the web-service, more users, slower response.

Comment: You can pre-allocate batches of unique ids and store them locally on each server for efficient handling of bursts.

Comment: I'll definitely consider this suggestions if I won't find anything more efficient. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In another forum someone suggests that I should convert current time to integer narrowed down to micro-seconds. How is this approach?

Comment: @ZohaibAslam I suspect using only the time, no matter what the granularity, poses a risk of collision.

Comment: Yes, I understand, it just reduces the probability of collision but it can happen whatsoever.

Comment: It doesn't reduce the probability enough. It's a bad solution. Don't do it.

Comment: Another flaw with using only the time is that it could pose a security threat. An attacker can easily guess the id of any transaction simply based on the time.

Comment: So the only option that is left here is to **keep track of the integers**. I should be using this approach thank you for the help. Also I am planning to write another script to be run as a crone job which will keep deleting the junk rows.

Answer (score 3):

Tons of solutions:

- keep track of your integers (flat file, database with integer key, autoincrement)
- prevent calls from being simultaneous (use locks, semaphores etc)
- use queue for your calls

Comment: I had these solutions in mind before posting this question but I hope that there is a more efficient way to do it without considering track of integers or using semaphores - which may lead to starvation when thousands of users are online at same time.

Comment: I dare to say that if you experience thousands of simultaneous users, then you will have more serious issues anyway :)

Comment: For now this is one serious issue. The call to Web-service deals with sending thousands of dollars. If a call will ever fail, that will be a very serious issue for the company for whom I am developing this website, and eventually, a serious issue for me :p

Comment: In that case you must use a queue so you can re-try failed requests. Design for failure. It will happen.

Comment: If a call fails, you should handle that appropriately.  You should never assume that all calls will succeed even with a unique id.

Comment: Echoing @MarcinOrlowski 's remark on `more serious problems`. Do the math, with 32 bits your are collision-bound in no time flat (ie. while you are still at that job)  :)

Comment: Web-service accepts only 32-bit integer so that is not my problem how they will handle, maybe there is a threshold after which it allows repetition of integers I'll definitely confirm it.

Comment: Thank you @Asaph I'll consider your suggestion too!

Comment: @ZohaibAslam if you are not doing realtime call then you should add the queue otherwise connectivity problems can wreck havoc on your system sooner than you expect.

Comment: In another forum someone suggests that I should convert current time to integer narrowed down to micro-seconds. How is this approach?

Comment: @ZohaibAslam Bad as well. Chances two hits will be exactly at the same moment are quite unlikely on single machine, but add another box (you remember, thousands of users :) and you may end dead. Simply assume that **if** anything can happen it **will** happen. And be ready in advance.

Comment: So the only option that is left here is to **keep track of the integers**. I should be using this approach thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned that you have tried `uniqid()`, which does not produce an integer directly, I assume that what you need can be a string, and you would simply like it to be unique.

This is what [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is for, and you can generate them in PHP using a library like [this](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) or a simpler approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875555/1710543).

Ah UUID is effectively a 128-bit integer, and you could convert it to decimal with a little effort if needed.

Comment: I need an integer, and only 32 bits long. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter with time and uniqid.

```
 $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;    
 $unique = time() . $_SESSION['counter'] . str_shuffle(rand(100,10000));
```

If 32 bits, then

$uniqMax = pow(2, 32);

Save in a db and check if it exists before unique code approval

Option 2: Use a seperate db that creates an id and supplies it upon request instead of inserting a row with a uniqid