# PHP Format preexisting V4 UUID

Tags: php, uuid

I have some php that return a V4 UUID, and example would be:
`a935941636384aa0b7560617c641cc2e`
I need a way to get this string in a varible in this format:
`a9359416-3638-4aa0-b756-0617c641cc2e`
`8chars - 4chars - 4chars - 13chars`

Please help me accomplish this .

Comment: There's a `substr` function, use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is poorly written and the example you gave is wrong.
The last part can only have have **12 chars**, also, you specified **4 groups**, when in fact the string is **split in 5**.

You can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), i.e.:

```
<?php
$uuid = "a935941636384aa0b7560617c641cc2e";
$part1 = substr($uuid, 0, 8);
$part2 = substr($uuid, 8, 4);
$part3 = substr($uuid, 12, 4);
$part4 = substr($uuid, 16, 4);
$part5 = substr($uuid, 20, 12);
```

---

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/iUPGxY)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$str = 'a935941636384aa0b7560617c641cc2e';
$str1 = substr($str, 0, 8);
$str2 = substr($str, 8 ,4);
$str3 = substr($str, 12 ,4);
$str4 = substr($str, 16 ,4);
$str4 = substr($str, 20 ,12);

$final = $str1.'-'.$str2.'-'.$str3.'-'.$str4;
```

Comment: You may want to test it again. How many chars do you have on first part ?

Comment: Oh! yes. sorry. Updated the answer

Comment: Still wrong, read the `substr` manual. The 1st arg of `substr` is the char # to start and the 2nd is the  # of chars to match - http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Ok, Now you've my answer ;)