# What set of chars is php's uniqid composed of?

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

I would like to prepare simple regular expression for php's `uniqid`. I checked  [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) manual looking for set of chars used as return value. But the documentation only mention that:

> @return string the unique identifier, as a string.

And

> With an empty prefix, the returned string will be 13 characters long. If more_entropy is true, it will be 23 characters.

I would like to know what characters can I expect in the return value. Is it a hex string? How to know for sure? Where to find something more about the uniqid function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation doesn't specify the string contents; only its length. Generally, you shouldn't depend on it.  If you print the value between a pair of delimiters, like quotation marks, you could use them in the regular expression:

```
"([^"]+)"    ($1 contains the value)
```

As long as you develop for a particular PHP version, you can inspect its implementation and assume, that it doesn't change.  If you upgrade, you should check, if the assumption is still valid.

[A comment in `uniqid` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#95001) describes, that it is essentially a hexadecimal number with an optional numeric suffix:

```
if (more_entropy) {
    uniqid = strpprintf(0, "%s%08x%05x%.8F", prefix, sec, usec, php_combined_lcg() * 10);
} else {
    uniqid = strpprintf(0, "%s%08x%05x", prefix, sec, usec);
}
```

Which gives you two possible output formats:

1. `uniqid()` - 13 characters, [hexadecimal number](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.0/ext/standard/uniqid.c#L82)
2. `uniqid('', true)` - 14 - 23 characters, [hexadecimal number with floating number suffix](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.0/ext/standard/uniqid.c#L79)
   [computed elsewhere](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.0/ext/standard/lcg.c#L72)

If you use other delimiters than alphanumeric characters and dot, you could use one of these simple regular expressions to grab the value in either of the two formats:

1. `[0-9a-f]+`
2. `[.0-9a-f]+`

If you need 100% format guarantee for any PHP version, you could write your own function based on [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

I admit, that it is unlikely, that the `uniqid` would significantly change; I would expect creating other extensions to provide different formats.  [Another comment in `uniqid` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959) shows a RFC 4211 compliant UUID implementation.  There was also a discussion [on stackoverflow about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid).

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the php site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#95001

If this is to be believed then the 13 character version is entirely hex.
However the 23 character version has:

- 14 characters (hex)
- then a dot
- then another 8 characters (decimal)

If you need to be entirely sure, you can verify this yourself: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c04c7854b764faee2548180eddb8c23288dcb5f7