# How to create a uuid with 8 or 16 characters use php?

Tags: php, uuid

I want generate an account ID ,total user account less than 500K,so i want make account ID as short as possible, so I want know how to generate 8 or 16 characters ID  use  php ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
echo strtoupper(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)));
```

This will generate 16 characters unique string

You can create common function also

```
function GUID() {
    return strtoupper(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)));
}
$id = GUID();
echo $id;
```

Comment: This would actually create a 32 character unique string.

Comment: use `8` instead of `16`
----
`strtoupper(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)));` will generate `16` characters