# How to generate JWT in PHP

Tags: php, jwt

How to generate JWT token in php using with the following parameters
Subject, Issuer, Expiry time and payload in the < PAYLOAD > tag.

- **Id** can be any random number of any length.
- **subject** is **TestService**
- **Issuer** is **Baguma Inc**
- **Expiry Time** will be 30 sec from current time(ideally ).
- **Payload** is the **request from Third Party**
- **SigningKEY** is **fcvxcnfrhrtghkfghgwerikdf**
- Signature algorithm will be HS512.

**Sample request from Third Party** is shown below

`<COMMAND><TYPE>REQUEST</TYPE><INTERFACE>TESTACCOUNT</INTERFACE> <REQUESTID>123</REQUESTID></COMMAND`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell I finally got the solution. I have shared it in the answer section. Hope it will be helpful to other developers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of an article from  [DZone Security](https://dzone.com/articles/create-your-jwts-from-scratch), I managed to generate a JWT token by doing the following

1. Define the base64UrlEncode function which replaces + with -, / with _ and = with ''.

```
function base64UrlEncode($text)
{
    return str_replace(
        ['+', '/', '='],
        ['-', '_', ''],
        base64_encode($text)
    );
}
```

2. Encode the headers using base64UrlEncode

```
$headers = [ "alg" => "HS512"];

$headers_encoded = $this->base64UrlEncode(json_encode($headers));
```

3. Encode the Payload using Base64 URL encode as well

```
$issuedAt = time();

    $payload =  [
        "id" =>$this->gen_uuid(), //   .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        "sub"=> "TestService", //Subject
        "exp"=> $issuedAt+30,
        "iss"=> "Baguma Inc",  //issuer
        "iat"=> $issuedAt,  //issued at
        "PAYLOAD"=> "<COMMAND><TYPE>REQUEST</TYPE><INTERFACE>TESTACCOUNT</INTERFACE> <REQUESTID>123</REQUESTID></COMMAND"];

      $payload_encoded = $this->base64UrlEncode(json_encode($payload));
```

4. Using the Key/secret build the signature

```
$key = "fcvxcnfrhrtghkfghgwerikdf";  
$signature = hash_hmac('sha512',"$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded",$key,true);
```

5 Encode the signature

```
$signature_encoded = $this->base64UrlEncode($signature);
```

6. Build and return the token

```
$token = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
```

Comment: How is `$signature_encoded` generated?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert thanks for that observation. Update has been done.

Comment: The last parameter "true" (binary) in hash_mac function can lead to generate multiple line in header and to break your http response.  I put it to false and it worked well for me with symfony rest controller.

Comment: @mik3fly-4steri5k if you're using php the parameter true is needed. Please refer to official/ verified libraries via https://jwt.io/libraries. But thanks for your feedback

Comment: well weird, it's with php 8 / symfony 6

Answer (score 11):

Your answer got me started. Here's the working code I went with (albeit generalized from your specific case). Thanks for getting me started!

```
function gen_jwt():String{
    $signing_key = "changeme";
    $header = [ 
        "alg" => "HS512", 
        "typ" => "JWT" 
    ];
    $header = base64_url_encode(json_encode($header));
    $payload =  [
        "exp" => 0,
    ];
    $payload = base64_url_encode(json_encode($payload));
    $signature = base64_url_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', "$header.$payload", $signing_key, true));
    $jwt = "$header.$payload.$signature";
    return $jwt;    
}

/**
 * per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid/15875555#15875555
 */
function base64_url_encode($text):String{
    return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($text));
}
```

Comment: No need for extra external libraries. Thanks a lot! JWT validates fine @ https://jwt.io/

Comment: Another Tip: For my target API I needed to change the algo & hmac to HS256 + sha256 to avoid an "Algorithm not allowed" error.

Comment: For decoding use `function base64_url_decode($text) {
    return base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $text));
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP Library like Firebase JWT
https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt