# How can I generate strong unique API keys with PHP?

Tags: php, uuid

I need to generate a strong unique API key.

Can anyone suggest the best solution for this? I  don't want to use `rand()` function to generate random characters. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: What do you define as "strong"?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564251/generate-a-unique-key

Comment: Actually, i don't want to use md5 or rand or custom function for this. I would expect some functions like UUID that's why i mentioned strong

Comment: @jd182 - No i had gone through that :)

Comment: I think you're confusing password hashing with generating a unique string. As someone else asked, what criteria would it need to meet in order to be strong enough?

Comment: define strong, define 'awesome' ?

Comment: Strong means - Unique API key should not be repeat again in any manner
Awesome means - Smart way i needed to do this stuffs :)

Comment: See also: [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15875555/1338292).

Answer (score -9, accepted):

This is the best solution i found.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959

Answer (score 12):

As of PHP 7.0, you can use the `random_bytes($length)` method to generate a cryptographically-secure random string. This string is going to be in binary, so you'll want to encode it somehow. A straightforward way of doing this is with `bin2hex($binaryString)`. This will give you a string `$length * 2` bytes long, with `$length * 8` bits of entropy to it.

You'll want `$length` to be high enough such that your key is effectively unguessable and that the chance of there being another key being generated with the same value is practically nil.

Putting this all together, you get this:

```
$key = bin2hex(random_bytes(32)); // 64 characters long
```

When you verify the API key, use only the first 32 characters to select the record from the database and then use `hash_equals()` to compare the API key as given by the user against what value you have stored. This helps protect against timing attacks. ParagonIE has [an excellent write-up](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/02/split-tokens-token-based-authentication-protocols-without-side-channels) on this.

For an example of the checking logic:

```
$token = $request->bearerToken();

// Retrieve however works best for your situation,
// but it's critical that only the first 32 characters are used here.
$users = app('db')->table('users')->where('api_key', 'LIKE', substr($token, 0, 32) . '%')->get();

// $users should only have one record in it,
// but there is an extremely low chance that
// another record will share a prefix with it.
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // Performs a constant-time comparison of strings,
    // so you don't leak information about the token.
    if (hash_equals($user->api_token, $token)) {
        return $user;
    }
}

return null;
```

### Bonus: Slightly More Advanced Use With Base64 Encoding

Using Base64 encoding is preferable to hexadecimal for space reasons, but is slightly more complicated because each character encodes 6 bits (instead of 4 for hexadecimal), which can leave the encoded value with padding at the end.

To keep this answer from dragging on, I'll just put some suggestions for handling Base64 without their supporting arguments. Pick a `$length` greater than 32 that is divisible by both 3 and 2. I like 42, so we'll use that for `$length`. Base64 encodings are of length `4 * ceil($length / 3)`, so our `$key` will be 56 characters long. You can use the first 28 characters for selection from your storage, leaving another 28 characters on the end that are protected from leaking by timing attacks with `hash_equals`.

### Bonus 2: Secure Key Storage

Ideally, you should be treating the key much like a password. This means that instead of using `hash_equals` to compare the full string, you should hash the remainder of the key like a password, store that separately than the first half of your key (which is in plain-text), use the first half for selection from your database and verify the latter half with `password_verify`.

Answer (score -2):

using mcrypt:

```
<?php
$bytes  = mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$unpack = unpack("Nint", $bytes);
$id     = $unpack['int'] & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score -3):

PHP has uniqid function http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php with optional prefix and you can even add additional entropy to further avoid collision. But if you absolutely possitevily need something unique you should not use anything with randomness in it.