# How to make a name of file in such way 31f3207.jpeg

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, file-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique key generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218/unique-key-generation)

How to automaticly make a new name of file when you upload it to server?

I upload a picture file with < input type="file" / >. File has name picture_1.jpg. But I'd like to store it in filesystem with name like this ec0b4c5173809b6aa534631f3207.jpg? How such new names are created? Is some special script/generator used to make such names?

For example picture in FB: `http:// a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/190074_10150167009837952_8062627951_8311631_4439729_n.jpg.`

The name of it is `190074_10150167009837952_8062627951_8311631_4439729_n.jpg`. But original name was different for sure. So I'd like to change the name of uploaded file the same way. How is it possible?

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. It would be helpful, to provide additional information and rephrase your question, like: "I want to do XYZ and keep track of the uploaded files. But i don't know how , because if i upload a file with a given name, the names get changed when stored on the server. I'm using XYZ as CMS/WebFramework and i provided a short log/transcribed below: ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP I use [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for naming files that I store from uploads

If you want an extra long or seemingly more random id, you can [sha1()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) or [md5()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) the uniqid to create a hash.

You could of course also use those two methods to create a hash of the filename.

For example, the following code can be used to generate a new name for a file

```
$file = 'somefile.jpg';
$new_name = uniqid();
$new_name .= '.'.pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what programming language you are using.

in PHP, that cryptic name and original filename can be found on array `$_FILES`.

let's assume your form's element name is userfile, you can get that cryptic name from `basename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])` and the original name from `basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])`

Visit here for more information : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0):

You could MD5 the name to create a string without spaces or dots: `md5($filename)` (http://php.net/md5) although I'm not sure that was what you were asking?

Edit: you could also use `uniqid()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: In some situations this would be a good approach; however, if two images had the same local filename (but uploaded by different users, for example) this would be problematic. I think the OP is looking for a function to create unique filenames on the server, regardless of their original, local filename.

Comment: What will happen if an user uploads a pic named me.jpg, and another one uploads another picture with the same name? Of course md5 can be used but not like that.

Comment: I was unsure whether he wanted a method of creating "safe" filenames or a way to generate unique ones, hence my edited reply. If you _did_ use `md5()` you would obviously need to make sure they're not already in use.

Answer (score 0):

You just rewrite the name of the file upon moving it from the temporary files on the server, to the location you want to move it to.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $filePN)
```

Where &filePN is the path and name of where you want to move the file to.
 
the special script that you're talking about, however, can be a multitude of things from an MD5 hash of the input name, to an incremented number to prevent overwrites.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a GUID.

If you are an ASP.NET programmer, use something like this:

```
string filename = new Guid().ToString() + ".jpg";
```